# Is it possible to have an example at endpoint level that populates all parameter's values in openapi spec?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I know that we can have examples in the drop down menu for each parameter in the openapi spec. This requires to select each example for each parameter.

[image: Example drop down menu for each parameter]

I was wondering if it is possible to have a drop down menu for the endpoint that we can select the example and that example has the values for all parameters in that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported - neither by the OpenAPI Specification nor in Swagger UI. Here's an existing feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1673